# How do use the properties of a UIImageView such us "center.x" and "frame" when it is an IBOutletCollection array?

Tags: xcode, uiimageview, nsarray, iboutlet, outlet

Ok, so I had an IBOutlet of a UIImageView that looks like this:

```
.h
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIImageView *ground;
```

Then I can Use the variable like this "ground.frame" And in my code looks like this:

```
.m
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,ground.frame)) {
   "STUFF"
}
```

This works fine, but then I found out that I needed an "IBOutletCollection". I changed the .h code for this:

```
.h
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *ground;
```

Now I dont know how to make the other to work since it gives me an error telling me "frame is not found on object of type NSArray."
So my question is how can I change the code in the .m file so that it works the same way as before but now as an array?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array is a collection of UIImageViews so you take an object off the array and query that.

Maybe...

```
for(UIImageView *xground in ground)
{

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(player.frame,xground.frame)) {
   //do stuff 
   break;

}

}
```

You ask each view in the array about its frame.

If you want to be really paranoid run a class check on the object to be sure it's an UIImageView coming off the array, but probably not necessary as your have already declared it as an array of UIImageView.

Comment: That didn't work. Is there another way to do this? I just want to assign multiple objects to the same outlet, so that they all do the same thing.

Thanks!

Comment: What didn't work? Querying all the views in the collection? Are you sure all the imageviews are wired up in IB

Comment: What do you mean by querying all the views on the collection? They are wired in IB.
And going back to your first answer, I just needed to add the for loop right? or is there something else I need to do? Thanks!

Comment: Note the mod to your original statement xground vs ground.